# How to print a document with the same template per page web asp.net vb

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, vb.net

I am new in asp.net using VB.Net language.

How can I print a document with the same template or header on every page?

If the GridView has more than 10 records, then the remaining records will be on the 2nd page with the template/header from the first page.

```vb
Protected Sub PrintGridView(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim dataGrid As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView
    dataGrid.DataSource = (From lst In _lstPrint Select New With {.Item = lst.Item, .Descricao = lst.TipoComponente, .Certificado = lst.Certificacao, .Corrida = lst.Corrida, .Qtd = lst.Qtd, .UnidMedida = lst.UnidadeMedida})

    Dim obj As New eLVM()
    obj.Id = Integer.Parse(Request.QueryString("id"))
    ' Disable Paging if all Pages need to be Printed.
    dataGrid.AllowPaging = False

    ' Re-bind the GridView.
    dataGrid.DataSource = (From lst In _lstPrint Select New With {.Item = lst.Item, .Descricao = lst.TipoComponente, .Certificado = lst.Certificacao, .Corrida = lst.Corrida, .Qtd = lst.Qtd, .UnidMedida = lst.UnidadeMedida})
    dataGrid.DataBind()

    ' For Printing Header on each Page.
    dataGrid.UseAccessibleHeader = True
    dataGrid.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
    dataGrid.FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter
    dataGrid.Attributes("style") = "border-collapse:separate"
    For Each row As GridViewRow In dataGrid.Rows
        If (row.RowIndex + 1) Mod dataGrid.PageSize = 0 AndAlso row.RowIndex <> 0 Then
            row.Attributes("style") = "page-break-after:always;"
        End If
    Next

    Using sw As StringWriter = New StringWriter()
        ' Render GridView to HTML.
        Dim hw As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
        dataGrid.RenderControl(hw)

        ' Enable Paging.
        dataGrid.AllowPaging = True
        'dataGrid.DataSource = _lstPrint
        'dataGrid.DataBind()

        ' Remove single quotes to avoid JavaScript error.
        Dim gridHTML As String = sw.ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "")
        Dim gridCSS As String = gridStyles.InnerText.Replace("""", "'").Replace(Environment.NewLine, "")

        ' Print the GridView.
        Dim script = "window.onload = function() { PrintGrid('" & gridHTML & "', '" & gridCSS & "'); }"
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript([GetType](), "GridPrint", script, True)
    End Using
    ' rest of the code ...
End Sub
```

[Sceenshot of the GridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TzPn.png)

I want that black part to be repeated on the header part of the 2nd page with the rest of the GridView records.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of wonder if trying to somehow convert a rendered table in HTML (that's what a gv becomes after the asp.net processing system has dealt with that control).

Thus, the end result is rather hard to control the page layout, and in fact web based printing is perhaps one of the most difficult tasks you can achieve.

As a result?

I think you MUCH better off to adopt a report builder system. Either consider the client side RDL report viewer. That so called RDL (Report definition Language) is much the same as SSRS reporting services, but without needing SQL server reporting services.

Not only does this allow a VERY nice layout and page system, but it also has a built in export to Excel, Word, and PDF.

So, it looks like this in action:

[image]

So consider using the RDL report control. It can be a bit of a pain to setup, but is something I would consider.

You need to google a step by step on how to setup + get the report viewer (and designers) working, and all of this can work without SQL server reporting services.

one link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started?view=sql-server-ver16